# How to undo shortcut that you already typed in emacs?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor, undo, emacs23

Suppose, you type a shortcut key in emacs (say `M-x`) and you realize that you did not want to do it. How do you undo a shortcut that you already typed?

I have tried `Esc-d` but that doesn't seem to do what I want. Typing `C-g` after a wrong input says that the shortcut is not defined.

What I want is a way to immediately come out of all the typed shortcuts and execute new shortcuts immediately.

I hope my problem seems clear.

Comment: Suppose I typed `C-x` by mistake, then if I press `C-g`, it says `C-x C-g undefined`.

Comment: This is a desired behavior. C-g is always cancel, so if you have a long keybinding there should never be a C-g anywhere in it. Therefore using C-g will say undefined and cancel.

Comment: There are other shortcut combinations, that will also give the same message ("not defined"). Then what makes `C-g` different from those other key combinations (eg: pressing `Esc-d`)

Comment: C-g is reserved for cancelling. So doing C-g **anywhere** will **always** cancel the command. Esc-d can be bound in the middle of another shortcut. For example try Esc-d in a buffer and you will see that it tries to cut the word at point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cancel is `C-g` in emacs no matter what the context is.

Comment: Unless you redefine it like I did once. Bad idea. :-)